SQL Server install failure - possible registry issue?
I've tried to install SQL Server on a Windows 10 system about 5 times in the past few days, and every time I'm getting the same error message. "Trying to increment registrykey 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls\hadrres.dll' failed. Please check if registry key is accessible." This seems to affect the installation of the Database Engine Services specifically, and I've tried this now with both the 2022 and 2019 SQL Server installs. Same error with both programs. Trying to access the SharedDlls registry key causes RegEdit to freeze up, which leads me to wonder if this is actually some kind of registry issue. I've confirmed that "hadrres.dll" exists in the System32 folder.
I've tried doing a clean uninstall of SQL (removing all instances from the programs list, removing all registry keys referencing SQL, etc.), installing as admin, installing both the 2022 and 2019 editions, and attempting to repair the install (also as admin). None of these seem to make a difference. I'll post the summary log from my last attempt below:
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2058616831
  Start time:                    2024-09-04 15:53:57
  End time:                      2024-09-04 16:01:40
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  PINKFROSTY
  Machine processor count:       12
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Home (10.0.19045)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2019 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2019
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       15
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\SQL2019\ExpressAdv_ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Express

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    true
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad$SQLEXPRESS
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, FULLTEXT, CONN, BC, SDK, SNAC_SDK, LOCALDB
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$SQLEXPRESS
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     true
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      true
  IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    SQLEXPRESS
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLJAVADIR:                    
  SQLMAXDOP:                     0
  SQLMAXMEMORY:                  2147483647
  SQLMINMEMORY:                  0
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           PINKFROSTY\Bazooka Joe
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20240904_155310\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x854C0001
  Error description:             Trying to increment registrykey 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls\hadrres.dll' failed. Please check if registry key is accessible.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0x21C1C994%400xAC7B1A58%401233%401450&EvtType=0x21C1C994%400xAC7B1A58%401233%401450

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x854C0001
  Error description:             Trying to increment registrykey 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls\hadrres.dll' failed. Please check if registry key is accessible.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0x21C1C994%400xAC7B1A58%401233%401450&EvtType=0x21C1C994%400xAC7B1A58%401233%401450

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x854C0001
  Error description:             Trying to increment registrykey 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls\hadrres.dll' failed. Please check if registry key is accessible.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0x21C1C994%400xAC7B1A58%401233%401450&EvtType=0x21C1C994%400xAC7B1A58%401233%401450

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       LocalDB
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures or warnings:

Global rules:
Warning    IsFirewallEnabled                The Windows Firewall is enabled. Make sure the appropriate ports are open to enable remote access. See the rules documentation at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2094702 for information about ports to open for each feature.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20240904_155310\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm


Likely, as you state, the initial installation needed to be as Administrator. If it was as a user, that might have left Registry changes that need to be manually removed. (Regrettably,  many changes. Perhaps some were missed.)

I honestly can't remember if the initial install was done with admin privileges or not, but there are two things making me think this isn't the only issue. First, I got the same error messages about the hadrres.dll registry key the first time I tried to install. Second, I've gone through the registry with a fine-tooth comb with every reinstallation attempt and deleted all entries related to SQL Server. It's possible I've missed some every time, but that just leaves me with the question of how to find all of them...

Might it be that SQL Server 2015 is not compatible with Win 10, or that the latest version would be easier to install (https://info.microsoft.com/ww-landing-sql-server-2022.html)? [Or consider Oracle - a breeze to install ;-) ]

I've been trying to install SQL Server 2022, and when I kept running into errors with that I tried the 2019 edition. Same error. I haven't ever touched 2015. I may have to look into Oracle if that's easier.

My last experience installing Oracle, admittedly years ago, both full DB and client, had been very positive, but must be done as Administrator: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html#db_free There are many possible additions, such as web extensions, which would make the process longer and harder. BTW, please report back your findings as an answer -- if it works, for you it can help others.
